# What is meant by "variable expansion"?

Tags: org-mode, variables

I'm looking at the ob-core.el source and see docstrings like:

> Expand variables in PARAMS...

The Emacs manual talks about macro expansion, which is when a macro is converted to executable source code (i.e. "the value returned by the macro body is an alternate Lisp expression").  It also talks about expanding an abbrev wherein a word (an abbrev) is replaced by something else (an expansion).  I don't see what variable expansion is, though.

What does it mean to expand a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That refers to headers that have `:var name=thing` in them, where thing may be the name of another block, table, or function. `thing` gets "expanded" and assigned to `name` so you can use `name` inside the src block.

For example:

```
#+name: tbl
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |

#+BEGIN_SRC python :var data=tbl
return data
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
```